# Installing repo from GitHub with composer

Tags: github, repository, composer-php

I'm trying to update this test extension to my project but I encountered an error:

```
adz@adz:/var/www/site$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
```

I also tried

```
adz@adz:/var/www/site$ php composer.phar require adz/yii2-featureditems:dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Package "adz/yii2-featureditems" listed for update is not installed.
Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Here is my `composer.json` file

```
{
    "repositories":[
        {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/adzayko/featured-items.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "adz/yii2-featureditems": "dev-master"
    }
}
```